# Кластеризация scipy python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Есть вот такой 2D массив точек, делаю кластеризацию

```
arr = [[-0.23849030299472848, 0.2863843214610768], [-0.23467813388970515, 0.2847352640189306], [-0.2317909064951051, 0.2841855891260814], [-0.2289130691192626, 0.28363588146963364], [-0.22692253320967895, 0.2841855891260814], [-0.22248365952322413, 0.2847352640189306], [-0.22046955601831614, 0.2852849389117798], [-0.2184460360522419, 0.28583461380462905], [-0.21518661446075313, 0.2863843214610768], [-0.24449391711024582, 0.28789444804930475], [-0.24017691601533098, 0.28570513231579364], [-0.23635297619353182, 0.2840631373598402], [-0.23345868645305706, 0.2835158165822825], [-0.23012780818500955, 0.28242114240388666], [-0.22813962653103548, 0.28296849580472483], [-0.22570543988832242, 0.28296849580472483], [-0.22370310695987225, 0.2835158165822825], [-0.22126421208657604, 0.2835158165822825], [-0.21967019171947313, 0.2846104581373978], [-0.21763963430643474, 0.285157811538236], [-0.21518661446075313, 0.285157811538236], [-0.20942313932443224, 0.2873470946484666], [-0.20773968579134428, 0.2884417688268624], [-0.24449391711024582, 0.28665616740968813], [-0.24017691601533098, 0.28447626827766126], [-0.23635297619353182, 0.2828413358079005], [-0.23345868645305706, 0.2822963691456344], [-0.23057381317374856, 0.28175140248336833], [-0.22813962653103548, 0.28175140248336833], [-0.22570543988832242, 0.28175140248336833], [-0.22370310695987225, 0.2822963691456344], [-0.22169135757025582, 0.2828413358079005], [-0.21967019171947313, 0.28338630247016655], [-0.21722188038501067, 0.28338630247016655], [-0.21518661446075313, 0.2839313016153952], [-0.21314190717641876, 0.28447626827766126], [-0.21025781549296677, 0.2855662016021934], [-0.20898032054625248, 0.2872011340719542], [-0.20728271854504865, 0.28829106739648636], [-0.24900238370090597, 0.2892162069415376], [-0.24017691601533098, 0.2832474042395289], [-0.23635297619353182, 0.2816195342559608], [-0.23345868645305706, 0.2810769217089863], [-0.23057381317374856, 0.2805343091620118], [-0.22813962653103548, 0.2805343091620118], [-0.22614200183316846, 0.2810769217089863], [-0.22370310695987225, 0.2810769217089863], [-0.22169135757025582, 0.2816195342559608], [-0.21967019171947313, 0.28216214680293533], [-0.21763963430643474, 0.28270479169255436], [-0.2155996352526835, 0.2832474042395289], [-0.21314190717641876, 0.2832474042395289], [-0.21149138776168228, 0.2843326293334779], [-0.2098220592009797, 0.28541788677007146], [-0.20813387366094213, 0.2865031118640205], [-0.20759531733071065, 0.2892162069415376], [-0.23849030299472848, 0.28147828176971357], [-0.23513117464159214, 0.28039773270402113], [-0.23223923901640894, 0.2798574742723382], [-0.22980034414311276, 0.2798574742723382], [-0.22736144926981655, 0.2798574742723382], [-0.22492255439652034, 0.2798574742723382], [-0.22248365952322413, 0.2798574742723382], [-0.22089434738670435, 0.2809379911357041], [-0.21886614422927556, 0.28147828176971357], [-0.21682849929081588, 0.2820185402013965], [-0.21437077121455114, 0.2820185402013965], [-0.21272496003039776, 0.2830990570647624], [-0.2106590657084393, 0.2836393154964454], [-0.2093768625311419, 0.28526012299382075], [-0.2080664094090737, 0.2868809304911961], [-0.23894805197719862, 0.28078967616326417], [-0.23513117464159214, 0.2791759311520815], [-0.23223923901640894, 0.2786380268356901], [-0.22980034414311276, 0.2786380268356901], [-0.22736144926981655, 0.2786380268356901], [-0.22492255439652034, 0.2786380268356901], [-0.22291315912219548, 0.2791759311520815], [-0.22089434738670435, 0.2797138354684729], [-0.21886614422927556, 0.2802517718468728], [-0.21682849929081588, 0.28078967616326417], [-0.21478143789118995, 0.2813275804796555], [-0.21272496003039776, 0.2818654847960469], [-0.21106033984059636, 0.28294132549083817], [-0.2093768625311419, 0.28401713412362095], [-0.20845824316338, 0.286168783451195], [-0.2372637930718877, 0.27902526192403193], [-0.2343600597262479, 0.2784896798012416], [-0.23101979157976085, 0.277418579399042], [-0.22858089670646464, 0.277418579399042], [-0.22657856377801447, 0.2779541296001418], [-0.22413496067413516, 0.2779541296001418], [-0.2221185030539356, 0.2784896798012416], [-0.22009265415211637, 0.27902526192403193], [-0.21805736332894826, 0.2795608121251318], [-0.2160126560446139, 0.2800963623262316], [-0.21395853229911327, 0.28063191252733144], [-0.212298620480213, 0.28170304485122155], [-0.2106198514013417, 0.2827741452534212], [-0.20931646076546617, 0.2843808277784111], [-0.23986354994213885, 0.27939834025861593], [-0.23603728314904687, 0.27779875200119114], [-0.23313590405901669, 0.2772655241340104], [-0.2302439684338335, 0.27673232804820214], [-0.22780036532995415, 0.27673232804820214], [-0.2253567622260748, 0.27673232804820214], [-0.22334265872116682, 0.2772655241340104], [-0.22089434738670435, 0.2772655241340104], [-0.21928622736708064, 0.2783319480869994], [-0.21724387419803784, 0.27886514417280767], [-0.21519210456782878, 0.27939834025861593], [-0.21353690111982965, 0.2804647642116049], [-0.21186284027154148, 0.2815311563832214], [-0.21056651212185865, 0.28313077642201867], [-0.24821243544227517, 0.28347325097717624], [-0.24077907519139588, 0.27922648357198826], [-0.23649032390093386, 0.277103084048867], [-0.23358426330336526, 0.27657224207835035], [-0.23068759272455422, 0.2760413684667792], [-0.22823928139009175, 0.2760413684667792], [-0.2257909700556293, 0.2760413684667792], [-0.22334265872116682, 0.2760413684667792], [-0.22131916407495716, 0.27657224207835035], [-0.21928622736708064, 0.277103084048867], [-0.21765924910525977, 0.2781647679899004], [-0.21560277124446758, 0.2786956099604171], [-0.21394285956588532, 0.27975732554250493], [-0.21226409048701403, 0.28081900948353833], [-0.2113595960916375, 0.28294240900665957], [-0.24385776822205926, 0.2801021543532721], [-0.23908537254060191, 0.27745968357641004], [-0.23571214649939692, 0.2764027078659598], [-0.23235775338052445, 0.2753457321555095], [-0.22946343705732297, 0.27481721279954796], [-0.2270151257228605, 0.27481721279954796], [-0.2249986938434796, 0.2753457321555095], [-0.22254567399779798, 0.2753457321555095], [-0.220515091405213, 0.27587422001073464], [-0.21889282137397528, 0.2769311957211849], [-0.21725174303867958, 0.2779882029323716], [-0.21518349432079353, 0.2785166907875967], [-0.21350943347250537, 0.279573666498047], [-0.21221545957843213, 0.2811591615644588], [-0.24695532174000798, 0.2809590235726419], [-0.24215232213880625, 0.27832832351255565], [-0.2383025139121626, 0.27674992229275497], [-0.23448092834597298, 0.27517148971253585], [-0.23157486774840438, 0.27464535597260226], [-0.22867822361200202, 0.2741192222326687], [-0.22665941159587488, 0.27464535597260226], [-0.22420168351961012, 0.27464535597260226], [-0.2221687468117336, 0.27517148971253585], [-0.2201263936426908, 0.2756976234524694], [-0.21849002367829623, 0.27674992229275497], [-0.21683479575234058, 0.27780218977262205], [-0.2147547764579967, 0.27832832351255565], [-0.2134678650501162, 0.27990675609277477], [-0.2452381049399791, 0.2791781302457327], [-0.2409069791533149, 0.2770829805270643], [-0.23706423327254594, 0.2755116416531383], [-0.23369568859856132, 0.2744640511837539], [-0.230346003710272, 0.2734164919344699], [-0.22788827563400724, 0.2734164919344699], [-0.2258624012720054, 0.2739402715591119], [-0.2238271104488373, 0.2744640511837539], [-0.22178240316450293, 0.2749878308083959], [-0.21972830431791288, 0.2755116416531383], [-0.21807778462254035, 0.2765592009024223], [-0.2164084320048353, 0.2776067601517063], [-0.21472027052180023, 0.27865435062109073], [-0.2439833453530035, 0.2779233706587571], [-0.23966163616782354, 0.275837637541573], [-0.2358259526329293, 0.2742733610135217], [-0.23246211632984584, 0.2732304789150384], [-0.22955605573227722, 0.27270905340568796], [-0.22709361942542935, 0.27270905340568796], [-0.2250606827175528, 0.2732304789150384], [-0.2234431462367628, 0.2742733610135217], [-0.2218067512331397, 0.2753162120322225], [-0.21973614839996208, 0.275837637541573], [-0.21806682026021357, 0.2768805196400562], [-0.21637863443953997, 0.2779233706587571], [-0.24272858576602788, 0.2766686110717815], [-0.23886697981892763, 0.27511136595014046], [-0.23503365039932494, 0.2735541517679639], [-0.2316698142365595, 0.27251597804038175], [-0.2287613995236993, 0.27199690664632287], [-0.22672610870053123, 0.27251597804038175], [-0.22468142687637946, 0.273035080373905], [-0.22304974010333947, 0.27407322316202276], [-0.22139922040796695, 0.27511136595014046], [-0.21972989240853644, 0.2761495396777226], [-0.21804170658786284, 0.27718768246584036], [-0.23976837995548123, 0.27489713420603856], [-0.23592560721134953, 0.27334695157059025], [-0.23255238088950853, 0.2723135170130557], [-0.22963454943484604, 0.2717967997342884], [-0.22758984186987566, 0.2723135170130557], [-0.22553571784373902, 0.27283023429182296], [-0.224317077042176, 0.2743804169272713], [-0.22223470335190454, 0.27489713420603856], [-0.2205559339923972, 0.2759305687635732], [-0.23681759060610083, 0.2731303655708788], [-0.23387619141579602, 0.27261597174857466], [-0.23050767332453811, 0.2715872454216232], [-0.22845354929840148, 0.2721016085850989], [-0.22639000881109855, 0.27261597174857466], [-0.22473951429527264, 0.2736447287343545], [-0.22307016139693156, 0.27467345506130597], [-0.23475875806874502, 0.27239232326267043], [-0.23181738518053088, 0.2718803142144863], [-0.22931728246774594, 0.2718803142144863], [-0.2276714707223205, 0.27290433231085465], [-0.22558438880146592, 0.2734163413590388], [-0.23143574948324735, 0.271649572723879], [-0.22935572990826747, 0.27215922765677164], [-0.158362024296018, 0.20225761684836369], [-0.15392890777223667, 0.20301797403207672], [-0.1636957140528517, 0.1998717154266011], [-0.16090029659335062, 0.19949389095003614], [-0.15781427233708054, 0.1987382419969062], [-0.15533771105784724, 0.1987382419969062], [-0.15286114977861395, 0.1987382419969062], [-0.15152818276412414, 0.20024953990316605], [-0.1498763763298324, 0.2013830358532446], [-0.16214849701306208, 0.19674899825467712], [-0.1593766209871127, 0.19637352789340373], [-0.15691418468026483, 0.19637352789340373], [-0.1541564333460648, 0.19599805753213034], [-0.15198931206656907, 0.19637352789340373], [-0.15038458849938066, 0.19749996135728956], [-0.14903278856255833, 0.19900184280238314], [-0.1630702754473845, 0.19514230973997979], [-0.16030075353672668, 0.19476919349399796], [-0.15784302546046194, 0.19476919349399796], [-0.15538529738419718, 0.19476919349399796], [-0.15292756930793244, 0.19476919349399796], [-0.15075809391314512, 0.19514230973997979], [-0.14914630785976402, 0.19626168071767292], [-0.14750625524146424, 0.19738102945561842], [-0.14611209756890556, 0.19887351667929337], [-0.16430149360080845, 0.19391109158655584], [-0.16152961757485906, 0.19354032945586558], [-0.1590718894985943, 0.19354032945586558], [-0.15661416142232956, 0.19354032945586558], [-0.1541564333460648, 0.19354032945586558], [-0.15169870526980006, 0.19354032945586558], [-0.14952687575972118, 0.19391109158655584], [-0.14790802722014737, 0.19502340007805627], [-0.1459844301509533, 0.1957649243394368], [-0.144313790233057, 0.19687723283093722], [-0.1762263276563203, 0.19636399750534214], [-0.17176127789900614, 0.19415352745383832], [-0.16863756865219895, 0.19341668946392931], [-0.1655327117542324, 0.19267987343313192], [-0.1630702754473845, 0.19267987343313192], [-0.16030075353672668, 0.19231146541773322], [-0.15784302546046194, 0.19231146541773322], [-0.15538529738419718, 0.19231146541773322], [-0.15292756930793244, 0.19231146541773322], [-0.15046984123166768, 0.19231146541773322], [-0.14829565760629723, 0.19267987343313192], [-0.14639089374007172, 0.19341668946392931], [-0.14446731329102547, 0.19415352745383832], [-0.1430637388766645, 0.19562718147454472], [-0.17365845793678242, 0.19364500049914438], [-0.17019707873324702, 0.19254683879882298], [-0.16708278608792412, 0.1918147091798151], [-0.16430149360080845, 0.19144865527970797], [-0.16152961757485906, 0.19108260137960084], [-0.1587671580100759, 0.1907165474794937], [-0.1563141381643943, 0.1907165474794937], [-0.1541564333460648, 0.19108260137960084], [-0.15140809847303108, 0.1907165474794937], [-0.14924097719353532, 0.19108260137960084], [-0.1470644394528733, 0.19144865527970797], [-0.14487848525104505, 0.1918147091798151], [-0.1429549046616808, 0.19254683879882298], [-0.1415466059578609, 0.1940110543992515], [-0.1720871964251486, 0.19203595772883747], [-0.16895879809363037, 0.19130855815920633], [-0.1658492138192086, 0.1905811369110996], [-0.16275848161299142, 0.18985373734146846], [-0.16030075353672668, 0.18985373734146846], [-0.1575406480872351, 0.1894900375566529], [-0.15538529738419718, 0.18985373734146846], [-0.15263460839587187, 0.1894900375566529], [-0.15046984123166768, 0.18985373734146846], [-0.14801211315540294, 0.18985373734146846], [-0.14583322129944937, 0.19021743712628403], [-0.14364491298232954, 0.1905811369110996], [-0.14198604378120905, 0.1916722579440219], [-0.14029890885707796, 0.1927633572984686], [-0.1720871964251486, 0.1907929688586377], [-0.16895879809363037, 0.1900702775195897], [-0.1658492138192086, 0.18934756464238411], [-0.1630702754473845, 0.1889862189728601], [-0.16030075353672668, 0.1886248733033361], [-0.15784302546046194, 0.1886248733033361], [-0.15538529738419718, 0.1886248733033361], [-0.15292756930793244, 0.1886248733033361], [-0.15046984123166768, 0.1886248733033361], [-0.14801211315540294, 0.1886248733033361], [-0.14583322129944937, 0.1889862189728601], [-0.14364491298232954, 0.18934756464238411], [-0.14171662402206414, 0.1900702775195897], [-0.1397694857999544, 0.1907929688586377], [-0.13832353674907322, 0.19223837307489128], [-0.17365845793678242, 0.18990897154267036], [-0.17019707873324702, 0.18883199687997304], [-0.16708278608792412, 0.1881139923736686], [-0.16430149360080845, 0.18775500081943616], [-0.16152961757485906, 0.18739600926520372], [-0.1590718894985943, 0.18739600926520372], [-0.15661416142232956, 0.18739600926520372], [-0.1541564333460648, 0.18739600926520372], [-0.15169870526980006, 0.18739600926520372], [-0.14924097719353532, 0.18739600926520372], [-0.14678324911727056, 0.18739600926520372], [-0.14460200314602542, 0.18775500081943616], [-0.14241134071361403, 0.1881139923736686], [-0.1404783433824475, 0.18883199687997304], [-0.13852649692975463, 0.18954997998843792], [-0.13732878046007624, 0.19134495915743968], [-0.17523442767899938, 0.1890202659961199], [-0.1720871964251486, 0.18830699111823815], [-0.16895879809363037, 0.1875937162403564], [-0.1658492138192086, 0.1868804201049531], [-0.1630702754473845, 0.18652378266601222], [-0.16030075353672668, 0.18616714522707134], [-0.15784302546046194, 0.18616714522707134], [-0.15538529738419718, 0.18616714522707134], [-0.15292756930793244, 0.18616714522707134], [-0.15046984123166768, 0.18616714522707134], [-0.14801211315540294, 0.18616714522707134], [-0.14583322129944937, 0.18652378266601222], [-0.14364491298232954, 0.1868804201049531], [-0.14144718820404342, 0.18723705754389397], [-0.13924006274283085, 0.1875937162403564], [-0.1375435113575335, 0.18866362855717903], [-0.13607402087310064, 0.19009019957046405], [-0.17523442767899938, 0.18777256889533697], [-0.1720871964251486, 0.18706400224803837], [-0.16895879809363037, 0.18635543560073975], [-0.1658492138192086, 0.18564684783623758], [-0.1630702754473845, 0.18529256451258827], [-0.16060783914053664, 0.18529256451258827], [-0.15784302546046194, 0.18493828118893896]]



import numpy
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hcluster

data = [[i[0], i[1]] for i in arr]

# clustering
thresh = 0.05
clusters = hcluster.fclusterdata(data, thresh, criterion="distance")

# plotting
plt.scatter(*numpy.transpose(data), c=clusters)
plt.axis("equal")
title = "threshold: %f, number of clusters: %d" % (thresh, len(set(clusters)))
plt.title(title)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А дальше не могу разделить вот этот объект на 3 разных, что можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Да я вижу что тут 1500 точек а у всех других по 200-300, но так же могут быть объекты в 100 точек, поэтому тупо 1500 на 300 я разделить не могу, объекты все имеют форму круга, поэтому сильно сливаться они не могут, только как на фото.

```
Counter({4: 1598, 8: 395, 2: 386, 3: 351, 6: 236, 5: 216, 7: 178, 1: 96})
```

Answer (score 2):

Если количество кластеров заранее известно, то примените метод k_Means или Spectral clustering.

Comment: нет, не известно (kmeans пробовал)